# Hardware options for hosting 5 websites

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting

I plan to buy hardware for my organisation that is supposed to host 5 websites each getting not more than 5000 hits a day. What kind of hardware would I require for this purpose in terms of processing power, memory etc. Could you suggest some options? I basically need a web and database server on the same machine. Please forgive me if the question phrased is not technically correct.

niting

Comment: My mobile phone? Really - this is LOW. Go lost ocst, low power unless the sites are heavy in calcualtions and / or you expect a lot more visitory.

Comment: hahaha - funny tomtom, very funny, and yet strangely possible :)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't, for such low-usage sites why buy, house and support hardware - just rent a virtual or dedicated server somewhere else, let the worries be someone else's. Obviously you could, if buzzwords are your thing, go for the almost identical option of using a 'cloud' provider and score some points with easily-impressed seniors.

Comment: +1 If it's only a handful of sites with fairly low hist, VPS all the way.

Comment: VPS all the way, and if you need more power, get more VPS.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this does not **appear** to be a heavy workload. Although if you're running 5000 queries per day on a 15Tb datawarehouse....that's a different story. You really haven't given much information about what you're trying to achieve here.

Nor have you said if this needs to be accessible via the internet - if no external access is required, **and** this is a basic OLTP app, then paying for hosting may just be overkill - if you already have the infrastructure then adding 5 new vhosts and a DBMS to an existing server or even a virtual image might be cheaper.

Certainly if you go down the route of a hosted solution, although basic packages may appear to offer what you need, IME (www.ralstonrats.co.uk) cheaper hosting can mean very high latency. If you've already got an ISP, go talk to them first about their hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly 5000 isn't much, look at getting a VPS as a dedicated server will be way over powered. You will most likely run out of bandwidth before server resources, unless you have very unoptimized sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a VPS server, put this in the cloud.

Comment: I really feel the need to state that VPS!=Cloud. A VPS would be good for this but not a true cloud depending on what these sites are.